# sql server send query and return an array without creating it the database

Tags: java, sql

I have a question.I am writing a programma at java using sql databases .Which i want to count how many duplicates there at a specific raw of a table of a database.I have found a query which finds the number of duplicates but it creates a new raw at the table of the database to save the data.Since i dont want to change the database structure (i want only to read data from it).How can i get the data of the query without having to create this table at the database?

Comment: If you run your query it should return the results without saving them into a table on your database.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using `TABLE` variable or `temp table` and then select the output of that `TABLE`

But first of all you should write the query or its logic here. Because it is not compulsory to **create a new raw** at the table.

Comment: I have already written the query which finds the n-plicates (dublicates, triplicates etc). But it saves them by creating a new array at the database i am wirking on.

Comment: there are `TABLE variable` in which you can store and get them as a output like : `SELECT * FROM @table1` . You can do these in a `STORED PROCEDURE`